# Bower install --save is not creating .bower.json file from bower.json

Tags: bower

So I have a pretty bogstandard bower.json file in a github repo:

```
{
  "name": "backbone-iobind",
  "description": "Bind socket.io events to backbone models & collections. Also includes a drop-in replacement for Backbone.sync using socket.io.",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/soniflow/backbone.iobind",
  "keywords": [
    "model",
    "view",
    "controller",
    "router",
    "server",
    "client",
    "browser",
    "socketio",
    "socket",
    "iobind"
  ],
  "author": "Noveo Group - Forked by Matt Fletcher",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://https://github.com/soniflow/backbone.iobind.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "~1.1.2"
  },
  "version": "0.4.8",
  "main": [
    "dist/backbone.iobind.js",
    "dist/backbone.iosync.js"
  ],
  "authors": [
    "Matt Fletcher <matt@soniflow.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

... and my dependencies are straight-forwards:

```
"dependencies": {
  "marionette": "~2.0.2",
  "backbone-io": "git://github.com/Soniflow/backbone.iobind.git"
}
```

However, when I do `bower install`, it copies all the files down as it should, but for some reason ignores my bower.json file and instead creates a .bower.json like so:

```
{
  "name": "backbone-io",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Soniflow/backbone.iobind",
  "version": "0.4.8",
  "_release": "0.4.8",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "0.4.8",
    "commit": "5e06d99d3e79b02bd8a892e3c6ba969e47f49736"
  },  
  "_source": "git://github.com/Soniflow/backbone.iobind.git",
  "_target": "*",
  "_originalSource": "git://github.com/Soniflow/backbone.iobind.git"
}
```

... which doesn't contain any of my metadata, and most importantly, the "main" directive.

Any idea why? I've used the same approach as backbone itself but that seems to work fine :/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower gets the list of a package versions from Git tags (they also need to be valid semver).
In the case of *backbone.iobind* the latest version is 0.4.8.
You can see that when resolving *backbone.iobind* Bower will checkout the [0.4.8 tag](https://github.com/Soniflow/backbone.iobind/tree/0.4.8):

```
bower resolved      git://github.com/Soniflow/backbone.iobind.git#0.4.8
```

However this tag **does not** contain any bower.json file (unlike the master branch).
The .bower.json file is an internal file used by Bower and should not be confused with bower.json.

Comment: Ah of course, I need to do a 0.4.9 release and use that. I've done that before in this situation actually- I'd just completely forgotten I'd need to do that :) Thanks!